# Regex for finding double "g"s in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble with regex. I want to find all instances of repeating "g"s in a string. If all "g"s are duplicates, then return True. If there is at least one lone "g" in the string, return False.
Examples:

```
xggt = True
xgt = False
poggpogpogg = False
poggpoggpogg = True
hello = False
hellog = False
hellogg = True
helloghellogg = False
hellogghellogg = True
```

I'm not asking for help in implementing code, just the regex expression to find the pattern I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your domain contains only lowercase letters:

```
"^([a-fh-z]*(gg)+[a-fh-z]*)+$"
```

This pattern accept strings like `teggggst` or just `gg`, which I think it matches your requirements. If you need to include uppercase letters or symbols to the pattern I hope you could finish this regex.